# groupby ID in a dataframe1 then use isin function in the grouped by data frame, with another dataframe2, and output a data frame as well

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, isin

I have two data frames:

first one is this :

[image]

which has 3 columns (ID , Name, Salary)

and the seconed data frame is this:

[image]

which has 2 columns (ID , Name)

I want to **groupby** ID in the first data frame (def1) after that I want to check if this **ID** **(isin)** the other data frame (def2), if it's **NOT** then I want to remove it. noting that the last output I need it to be as data frame  as well,  which is this:

[image]

how can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please don't post pictures of your data.  Copy/Paste the data into the question and format it as a table.

Comment: would `df.merge(df2['ID'])` be sufficient?

Comment: I am sorry this is my first question to ask, so I am not used to the right way/format of questions. Thank you for advising me :).

Comment: No, I need to do the groupby first to get mu desire output

Comment: you can indeed `merge` on ID+Name, or set them as index and slice